# how could I loop an array with a scanner input

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

how could I make a If or else statement and loop the input for the array
    package songsort;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Songs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
int num = 0;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

         int[] songAmount = new int[num];
        if () {}
         songAmount[0] = sc.nextInt();

    }

}
```

Comment: If does not loop. Look to use a for loop or a while loop instead. Any intro to Java control structures and program flow tutorial will help you

Answer (score 0):

The if condition cannot be empty. Did you try compiling the code? You'll get this error:

> Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token

Besides that, you scan the input for an integer value and store it at `songAmount[0]`. You'll override the value at `songAmount[0]` until your scanner finishes.
What you want to use is a for loop or a while loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    songAmount[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

However, your `num` seems to be zero, so what's the purpose of your code? Are you trying to save as many integers as your scanner reads? If so, you should use a `List` instead.